# Lamp server doesn't restart

Tags: server, apache2, 18.04, mysql, restart

I'm new with Ubuntu and Terminal, I have Ubuntu 18.04. First time I installed LAMP server using tasksel...and everything was working fine, and then, after some time, I can't start anything. I tried to use some commands but all i see is: can't restart because of error.

I remove all thinking it might help, and then it's all good. But i don't want to delete and install every time that server. Can somebody tell me what might be the problem and how to fix it?

If I use `sudo apache2ctl restart`this happens:

```
(2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory 
'/var/log/apache2/' for main error log
(2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory 
'/var/log/apache2/' for error log of vhost defined at 
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1
AH00014: Configuration check failed  
Action 'restart' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

EDIT: now everything's working except mysql service.
I tried `systemctl status mysql.service`
and this happened:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor 
preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-07-10 19:53:53 CEST; 
6s ago
Process: 6021 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid- 
file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited
Process: 6012 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre 
(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Why I can't restart it or anything?? Please help

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory: "(2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for main error log" means that it can't access its logging directory.  Did you verify that `/var/log/apache2/` exists as a directory?

Comment: @ThomasWard well, I see now, it doesn't exist. But I don't understand why those folders are deleted, and what should I do because I have installed all the packages for the server:(

Comment: On package installation it creates that directory usually.  Sometimes the packaging system doesn't work properly thoug and you have to create the directory.  Create that directory and see if Apache starts after that.

Comment: @ThomasWard Thank you :), now everything is okey except mysql, it is still stopped

Comment: Your question never touched upon MySQL so I can't help you there.  I'll move my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you got is pretty self-explanatory:

```
No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/'
```

Make sure the directory `/var/log/apache2/` exists, and if it does not, create it and launch Apache again.

While this directory should be made on installation, sometimes the package manager does a stupid and doesn't create it.  So you can recreate it fairly easily with `sudo mkdir /var/log/apache2/` and it should then work.